# Rails: How do I include gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies

This is a noob question:

How do I add gems to my rails app in a way that I can just copy my app's directory structure to a remote location and have it just work, with all the gems I depend on installed and available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The future-proof solution is to use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), which is required in Rails 3 and can be used right now in Rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

gems path in a directory is

```
RAILS_ROOT/vendor/gems
```

you have to freeze/unpack all the gems used in this directory

Rails gems and their dependancies path will be

```
RAILS_ROOT/vendor/rails
```

And all plugins path should be

```
RAILS_ROOT/vendor/plugins
```

By default Rails load the gems form the machine (or you can say local).
to load gems from the gems directory you have to add following code in tour 
**config/enviorment.rb**

```
  config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/gems/**"].map do |dir| 
    File.directory?(lib = "#{dir}/lib") ? lib : dir
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As x1a4 said, Bundler is the way to go, but an alternative (easier in the short term) is to [unpack](http://blog.logeek.fr/2008/12/23/how-to-freeze-gems-with-rails-2-1) (freeze) your gems.

In your `config/enviroment.rb` file, inside the `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|` block, define which gems you depend upon like so:

```
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
config.gem 'nokogiri'
```

(The `:version` and `:source` attributes are optional.)

In the command line, go to your app root directory and enter:

```
rake gems:install
rake gems:unpack
```

Your gems should show up in a folder named `vendor\gems` in your app. (I believe) your app will automatically look there first for any gems it requires.

Unfortunately, if the gem you want requires a native extension, you can't unpack it into your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add gems in a non-standard location for rails 2.3, you can add lines like these to config/environment.rb:

```
$:.push("/home/_whatever_/ruby/gems")
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/_whatever_/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

This is useful for example if you have added gems to your rails installation on hostgator.com

To help your rake tasks work correctly, add these lines to .bashrc:

```
export GEM_HOME=/home/_whatever_/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```